# How to use data-remote in bootstrap-validator by 1000hz

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using [bootstrap-validator](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator) to validate unique email on my form. `data-remote` does not seem to be working correctly. Can anyone show me a simple example how to use `data-remote`?

This is what I tried to do:

```
<input type="email" data-remote="check_email.php?data=email" required  name="user_email">
```

The `check_email.php` function returns true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't read the [documentation](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-markup):

> `data-remote="/path/to/remote/validator"` to make an AJAX request to determine if the field is valid or not. Be sure to give the input a name attribute, as the request will be sent to `/path/to/remote/validator?<name>=<value>`. The remote endpoint **should return a `200 OK` if the field is valid, and a `4xx` otherwise**.

Therefore, it doesn't look at the body of the response, only the response status code. So in your PHP you need something like:

```
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
   http_response_code(200); // Email is good
}
else {
    http_response_code(418); // I'm a teapot. Email is bad.
}
```

Comment: Is there an error in your PHP somewhere? Check the error logs.